# AWS Glue - Create Dynamic Frame for Dynamo DB Table having columns with mixed type

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

DynamoDB Table:

```
+------------------+---------+---------------------+
|        id        |Column A |             Column B|
+------------------+---------+---------------------+
|1                 |  "155.2"|                 400 |
|2                 |      100|                 200 |
|3                 |  "455.2"|               305.5 |
|4                 |  "312.3"|                 350 |
+------------------+---------+---------------------+
```

Notice that in Column A. We have numbers stored as strings except for id = 2.

Following code is used to read the table contents into a Dynamic Frame:

```
def create_dynamic_frame(table_name):
    ddb_s3_bucket = <some-s3-bucket>
    ddb_table_arn = <some-table-arn>
    connection_options = {
        "dynamodb.export": "ddb",
        "dynamodb.unnestDDBJson": True,
        "dynamodb.tableArn": ddb_table_arn,
        "dynamodb.s3.bucket": ddb_s3_bucket,
        "dynamodb.s3.prefix": 'temporary/ddbexport/'
    }
    dynamic_frame = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
        connection_type="dynamodb",
        connection_options=connection_options,
        transformation_ctx="dynamic_frame",
    )
    return dynamic_frame

dyf = create_dynamic_frame('test-table')
```

The output of show on the created Dynamic Frame: `dyf.toDf().show()`

```
+------------------+---------+---------------------+
|        id        |Column A |             Column B|
+------------------+---------+---------------------+
|1                 |     null|                 400 |
|2                 |     100 |                 200 |
|3                 |     null|               305.5 |
|4                 |     null|                 350 |
+------------------+---------+---------------------+
```

The output of `dyf.toDf().printSchema()`:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Column A: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Column B: string (nullable = true)
```

Notice that the string values in Column A are `null`. I was under the impression that Glue keeps both types in the column and you can use `resolveChoice` to then cast to whichever type you would want.

Is there a way I can resolve the type in the Glue-DDB connector?

I tried to resolve the types using `resolveChoice`:

```
resolved_dyf = dyf.resolveChoice(specs = [("Column A", "cast:string")])
```

This did not work, since the values in `dyf` itself are `null`

Answer (score 1):

When using "unnestDDBJson" it's forced to resolve and flatten the schema, I think you are will need to avoid that in your case and do it yourself after you have resolved the type.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a limitation of [the "connectionType": "dynamodb" with the AWS Glue DynamoDB export connector as source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-dynamodb:%7E:text=%22connectionType%22%3A%20%22dynamodb%22%20with%20the%20AWS%20Glue%20DynamoDB%20export%20connector%20as%20source)

Moreover, if we use `unnestDDBJson` parameter, Glue is forced to evaluate schema for the columns. If I do not use the `unnestDDBJson` parameter, all column values are kept as `struct` and I could not find a resource to then resolve the type.

One workaround for this is using the ["connectionType": "dynamodb" with the ETL connector as source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-dynamodb:%7E:text=%22connectionType%22%3A%20%22dynamodb%22%20with%20the%20ETL%20connector%20as%20source)